# symfony: Validating form field, many-to-many-relationship

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I have three entities: `User`, `Work` and `Journal`. There is a many-to-many-relationship between `User` and `Work` defined as follows:

In the `Work` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="peerReviewedWorks")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="test_work_user_peer")
 */
private $peerReviewers
```

In the `User` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Work", mappedBy="peerReviewers")
 */
private $peerReviewedWorks;
```

There is no relationship between my third entity, `Journal`, and `User` but a one-to-many-relationship between `Journal` and `Work`:

`Journal` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Work", mappedBy="journal")
 */
private $works;
```

`Work` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Journal", inversedBy="works")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="journal_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $journal;
```

From the `Work` controller I am creating a form which lets the editor choose the peer-reviewers from a list and assign them to a work:

```
<?php

public function manageAction(Request $request, Work $work)
{
    // ...
    $form = $this->createForm(ManageWorkType::class, $work);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The `ManageWorkType` class looks as follows:

```
<?php

class ManageWorkType extends AbstractType
{  
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder
        // add some stuff
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class)
    ;

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $work = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        // form field only added when journal is peer-reviewed
        if($work->getJournal()->getIsPeerReviewed() == 1) {

            // get a list of all active peer-reviewers
            $form->add('peerReviewers', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'PlatformBundle:User',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where('u.peerReviewStatus = :status')
                        ->setParameter('status', 'active')
                    ;
                },
                'multiple' => true,
            ));
        }
    });

    // ...
}
```

Since not every journal requires the same number of peer-reviews, I have a field `number_of_peer_reviewers` in the `Journal` entity which holds the number of required peer-reviewers:

`Journal` entity:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="numberOfPeerReviewers", type="string", length=1, nullable=true)
 */
private $numberOfPeerReviewers;
```

Before assigning the peer-reviewers from the `User` entity to the `Work` entity I have to check if the editor who submitted the form selected the required number of peer-reviewers from the list. If this is not the case the form should not be valid.

In order to achieve this I tried to use a callback validator in the `Work` entity but failed miserably:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="peer_reviewed_works")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="test_work_user_peer")
 * @Assert\Valid 
 */
private $peerReviewers;

// ...

/**
 * @Assert\Callback
 */ 
public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload)
{
    if(count($this->getPeerReviewers()) < $this->getPeerReviewers()->getNumberOfPeerReviewers()) {
        $context->buildViolation('Error message')
            ->atPath('peerReviewers')
            ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

As you can see I do not know how to access the `number_of_peer_reviewers` field from the `Journal` table.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, I am not sure if I fully understand: 1 `Work` object has 1 `Journal` property. `$numberOfPeerReviewers` is part of a `Journal` and you need the `$numberOfPeerReviewers` from the `Journal` related to the work, right? Than why not `$this->getJournal()->getNumberOfPeerReviewers()` ? Or do you need the `length=1` attribute?

Comment: $this->journal->getNumberOfPeerReviewers()